# Can we run VB.Net in Visual Studio Express that is initially installed with C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, installation, visual-studio-express

I have installed Visual Studio Express version for C#. Now I need to use VB.Net. However I don't see VB.Net *files*. And I tried searching to install both, but it seems both comes separately...

How can I install Visual Studio Express, so that it can support both C# and VB.Net?

Comment: Just install the VB.NET version. They exist side by side just fine. The alternative is to upgrade (and pay) for VS Professional, which will allow both in the same version of VS.

Comment: @KenWhite it seems 2010 Express All in One and 2012 Express has both :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Visual Studio 2010 you need to download the "Visual Basic 2010 Express" version from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2010-express

Install link - http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9709929

For some reason they decided to split the desktop edition into three one for C#, one for VB.NET and one for C++. You can install all three (or four if you include the Web Application Developer version) along side each other without any problems. They are designed to work like this.

The Visual Studio 2012 version (Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Desktop) includes C#, VB.NET and C++ in one application.

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-express-windows-desktop

You can install this along side your 2010 versions if necessary.

Comment: IC, I have installed VS 2010 C#. I think that's why it doesn't have VB.Net support. I will try and see if I can upgrade to 2012 without a full re-installation, may be then that will support both :)

Comment: @aspiring - The 2012 version should sit along side the 2010 version. You can also install all three 2010 versions (four if you include the Web Developer version) along side each other.

Comment: I just saw `Visual Studio 2010 Express All-in-One ISO` - this too seems to have both C# and VB.. I will try thanks again. (I upvoted, but will accept answer after 7 minutes: System says so :))